# Group by Length javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a array `a = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]` and I want to count length of each string in this array and return an object:

```
{
    3: ["one", "two"],
    4: ["four", "five"],
    5: ["three"]
}
```

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: What you've done so far, can you please post the code

Comment: I map this array and use ```Object.assign({}, [item.length]: item);``` but it not works :D

Comment: Please always post the code and effort you've done so far, so that people can point out where it went wrong and it will help you learn. you need to loop over array and build an object whose keys are based on string length and value will strings of that length.

Comment: Duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
const result = {}

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  const item = a[i]

  const length = item.length

  if (!result[length]) {
    result[length] = []
  }

  result[length].push(item)
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
const b = {}
a.forEach(str => {
  if (b[str.length]) {
    b[str.length].push(str);
  }
  else {
    b[str.length] = [str];
  }
})
console.log(b)
```

output:

```
{
  3: ["one", "two"],
  4: ["four", "five"],
  5: ["three"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `reduce`

```js
const strings = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]


const result = strings.reduce((res, s) => {
  const strLength = s.length
  const existing = res[strLength] || []

  return {
    ...res,
    [strLength]: [...existing, s]
  }

}, {})


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the strings by their length.

```js
const 
  strs = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
  result = strs.reduce((r, s) => {
    if (!r[s.length]) {
      r[s.length] = [];
    }
    r[s.length].push(s);
    return r;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```

You can also do it more concisely, as shown below:

```js
const 
  strs = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
  result = strs.reduce((r, s) => ((r[s.length] ??= []).push(s), r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ooooo  ??= didn't know about this!

Comment: @bturner1273 It's a more concise way of saying: `r[s.length] = r[s.length] ?? []`, just like `+=`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

const result = a.reduce((acc, item) => (
  Object.keys(acc).find(key => key == item.length) 
    ?? (acc[item.length] = []), 
  acc[item.length].push(item), 
  acc
), {})

console.log(result)
```